# How to activate a dependencies object on test system?

Tags: hana, hana-studio

I have a big model with views and procedures implemented in HANA. These Objects are interdependent. On the development System every things work fine. After we Transport the objects using CTS on the Test-System, we got all the objects on Test-System marked red. If I run this Statement on Test-System:

```
select * from "SYS.OBJECTS" where OBJECT_NAME like '%<my_package>%';
```

I got nothing!

Is this a settings Problem on the Test-System? Can I transport a lot of dependence objects at once?

Comment: If you've been working on this problem for a week, you will surely be able to provide the actual CTS error messages?

Comment: Hi vwegert. Thanks for replay. I got These error-message: error-code: 40117,error-msg: Repository: Encountered an error in repository runtime extension;Model inconsistency. Deploy Calculation View: SQL transaction rolled back by an internal error: invalid name of function or procedure <my_procedure>. But this make no sense. I already 100% add the <my_procedure> in a Change-ID and I reference the Change on Delivery_Unit, which referrence on a CTS. I can see the object on the Test-System but is not active. So, I redeploy the object manuelly and it seems to be active (no more red marked)

Comment: If I redeploy the active object again it returns red. Is it perhaps missing an authorization?